# WebBrowser control opens up a new window

Tags: webbrowser-control, facebook-oauth

I am working on a WPF client where I use Facebook Authorization. I am using the WebBrowser control and show the login page of facebook, then some redirects,  and in the end it shows  me my page with a access token in the url.

Then I grab this token and save it, I call Close() on my form. The window closes but almost right after the IE pops up a separate window showing the success page.

How can I stop this new window from popping up?

Here is my code (some of it)

```
private void WebBrowserNavigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{

   string url = e.Url.ToString();

   var result = Regex.Match(url, @"access_token=(?<token>[\d|\w]+)&");
   if (result.Success)
   {
      string token = result.Groups["token"].Value;
      Reader.SetAccessToken(token, SocialNetworkInformation.SocialNetwork.Facebook, url: e.Url);

       this.Close();
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Not the nicest way but it works.

Instead of closing the form right after i receive the response i call a delegate method that closes this form. Setup a timer on 0,3 seconds. The the window exist long enough to receive the answer but hardly long enough for the user to see the response.